# How to pass multiple arguments to a template tag with multiple "as" arguments in Django Template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, arguments, templatetags

With [@register.simple_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags), I defined the custom tag `test()` which has 2 parameters as shown below:

```py
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.simple_tag
def test(first_name="John", last_name="Smith"):
    return first_name + " " + last_name
```

Then, I pass `"Anna"` and `"Miller"` to `test()` with two `as` arguments in Django Template as shown below:

```
{% test "Anna" as f_name "Miller" as l_name %}
{{ f_name }} {{ l_name }}
```

But, there is the error below:

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'test' received too
> many positional arguments

Actually, there is no error if I pass only `"Anna"` to `test()` with one `as` argument as shown below:

```
{% test "Anna" as f_name %}
{{ f_name }}
```

Output:

```
Anna Smith
```

And, there is no error if I pass `"Anna"` and `"Miller"` to `test()` without `as` arguments as shown below:

```
{% test "Anna" "Miller" %}
```

Output:

```
Anna Miller
```

So, how can I pass multiple arguments to a template tag with multiple `as` arguments in Django Template?

Answer (score 0):

`as` argument can store the return values from the template tag `test()` according to the doc below in [Simple tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags):

> It’s possible to store the tag results in a template variable rather than directly outputting it. This is done by using the `as` argument followed by the variable name. Doing so enables you to output the content yourself where you see fit:

And according to my experiments, it is impossible to pass multiple arguments to a template tag with multiple `as` arguments in Django Template.

But, you can pass multiple arguments to a template tag with only one `as` argument in Django Template as shown below:

```
{% test "Anna" "Miller" as full_name %}
{{ full_name }}
```

Output:

```
Anna Miller
```